# Require multiple files in webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am trying to require all the files from **xyz** directory using webpack, but it throwing me console error saying

> Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object

Here is sample code :

```
export default require('angular')
      .module('app', [
           require('angular-animate'),
           require('angular-resource'),

           require.context('../xyz/', true, /.routes$/) // Requiring all the route files from xyz directory          
      ]);
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: is this in grunt or gulp or without both ?

Comment: Using only webpack.

Comment: is this controller file in ES6, why r u using require there

Comment: Yes its in ES6. What do you suggest?